# Macro to copy/paste dynamic range

Tags: dynamic, macros, range, global

I'm trying to copy and paste a two cell range from one sheet to another, changing the column of the original two cell range between each iteration. Here's the error:

*Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed*

And the code, with error section beginning with "lat" below:

```
Dim itr As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim year As Double
Dim LCOE As Double
Dim lat As Double
Dim longi As Double


'Select latlong
For i = 5 To 6
     Worksheets("Txmkt").Select
     lat = Range(i & 4).Value
     Sheets("Dashboard").Select
     Range("G4").Value = lat

     Sheets("Txmkt").Select
     longi = Range(i & 5).Value
     Sheets("Dashboard").Select
     Range("G5").Value = longi


    Call productionUpdate

'Select year
    For itr = 9 To 12
        Sheets("Txmkt").Select
        year = Range("D" & itr).Value
        Sheets("Dashboard").Range("D11") = year

        Call solvePPA

        LCOE = Range("D42").Value
        Sheets("TXmkt").Range(Cells(itr, i)) = LCOE

    Next itr


Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to run the code I got an error on this line

```
lat = Range(i & 4).Value
```

This is not the correct syntax. Try the below where i = the row# and 4 is your column#

```
lat = Cells(i, 4).Value
```

Same for every other area of your code where it is written this way.